# Style overflow:hidden and SVG Firefox 3.6

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I would like to display an svg that flows over the screen but I don't want to see scroll bars.  setting overflow:hidden in the body works for chromium and opera but not for Firefox 3.6.  Anyone know a fix? Thanks.

Comment: To what element are you applying overflow: hidden? How is the html structured with respect to the SVG?

Comment: ...and how are you embedding the SVG within the HTML? Via XHTML directly? Via an `<object>` or `<iframe>` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html, body { overflow:hidden }
```

Works for me: http://phrogz.net/tmp/wide_svg.xhtml

Comment: Ah I was just doing `body {overflow: hidden}` which worked in the other browsers.  Styling `html` does the trick for FF.  Thanks!